# MQTT over websocket in c

Tags: websocket, mqtt

I have implemented mqtt using server connection tcp socket on my machine with mosquitto broker. I have totally understood the mqtt protocol and its frame format. I want to publish my data over webserver which supports mqtt over websocket.

How can I start with this thing?

I am not clear with websocket concept
Can I implement websocket using tcp or is there any other method.
do i have to use http to implement mqtt over web socket as to send data over webserver?
As http and mqtt use different methods to send or receive data.

I don't want to use ready libraries such as paho.
I am totally new to this socket programming.any help or guideline will greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websockets are an extension  to the HTTP protocol, you need to use a correctly formatted HTTP request to setup a new Websocket connection.

Once the connection is setup it can be used to send the exact same binary MQTT packets that you would send over an existing TCP connection.

I suggest you look at using an existing library like libwebsockets to handle the Websocket connection setup, then you should be able to interface your existing code to just use the websocket handle instead of the socket handle.

If you REALLY don't want to use a library then you will need to start by reading the Websocket RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Comment: thank you for your reply... i have implemented http using openssl library...according to your answer do you mean  that i should send mqtt packets via post method that we use in http?

Comment: No, you need to read the Websocket RFC I linked to. It explains how to upgrade a HTTP connection to a Websocket connection and then how to send/receive data. As I said you REALLY should use something like libwebsocket

Comment: Ok sure I will try with that